# Is there a way to see what happened with votes?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I worked hard to provide what I think is a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33066672/286685) to a good question that did not yet have a good answer (imho), only to see it downvoted into the negative, even though it had quickly gotten some upvotes initially.

The currently accepted answer is actually an answer to a subtly different question, which also has unpleasant side effects (such as needless HTTP requests and errors in the console) so I downvoted it and provided a comment on what the problems with the approach were and left an answer with the (imho) correct solution.

Is there a way for me to see the voting history and individual votes (presumably anonymously) so I can see where the current count comes from?

Comment: You can see the votes cast in your profiles reputation tab. Is it this what you mean?

Comment: There's no upvotes on that answer...

Comment: @TZHX Yes you are right, just saw it now. Weird I could have sworn I got an upvote on it yesterday.. Must be confused... Anyhow it *should* have upvotes on it!  :p

Comment: FWIW, You answer *looks* good. I won't vote myself as I don't know enough about the JS to make an informed decision. However it has all the markings of a good answer.

Comment: @JamesWebster Thanks... I feel a bit cry-baby about nagging about downvotes but I feel this is one of my better answers actually. I really put some work in it so the downvote kinda hurt :(

Comment: in my observation, any posts on meta may probably attract more down votes, the score may soon to be -2 or lower

Comment: I'm not voting (mainly because I resist the meta effect), but I can reason that manual overriding is actually worse than using a pre-existing plugin to get it done. Still, nothing to actually downvote for, its a neat trick to be sure.

Comment: @Gimby The answer with the plugin I did not touch... He is actually writing a new plugin for it BTW, not using an existing one. But the top-ranked answer is actively saying that it cannot be done when it clearly can and is actually a lot simpler. Also, the top answer has some nasty side-effects, such as errors in the console and HTTP requests fired.

Comment: @amuse If that's true it would very much disappoint me. In my experience answers on stack overflow are evaluated based on their merit, not on the person who wrote them. It's why I love this site so much!

Comment: @StijndeWitt if you think there is a technical glitch with other answers, mention it clearly. And explain the reason why you think so. This will be taken well by future readers. Do not think that highly voted answers are always good. If you have a better answer, then post it and explain the reason neatly.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Yes, I actually did that. I added a comment about the issues and referred to it in my answer.

Comment: @amuse I'm sorry to have to say you were right... Score currently at -3... And no comment/explanation of why the answer is not good..   :(

Comment: Tough crowd. Well this was my first experience on meta. Can't say I enjoyed it. If the goal was to chase me away y'all doing a great job. :(

Comment: "In my experience answers on stack overflow are evaluated based on their merit, not on the person who wrote them." who guarantees that? Down votes can be arbitrary in practice, I guess the reason may be unpleasant to see long answers, looking down the up vote beggars, or even may only want to anger you

Comment: hey, @Stijn, here on Meta votes are like a cheap currency, but on your answer in the main site I can't see why of the downvotes, looks like a *pro* answer. It's really a pity if downvotes on this question went over there... Anyways, hope you don't give up on Meta :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to see the voting history and individual votes?

The [closest tool that exists](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) to what you want is the ability to see the sum of upvotes and the sum of down votes separately. This exists as a 1k reputation privilege. I don't know of a way to view the *history* of votes.

[image]
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)

---

There's also the [post timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14164610/timeline) – [Jon Clements♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements)

Comment: Wow so simple! Ha ha! I've been hanging around here for years and just now noticed this for the first time. I can't believe I never found this. Thanks!

Comment: There's also the [post timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14164610/timeline)

Comment: @JonClements, well there's something I didn't know existed!

Comment: @JonClements That's pretty much exactly what I was looking for! If you make that an answer I will accept it. - Nvm I see you were so kind to edit it into this answer.  :)

Answer (score 4):

You've made some technical claims in your Meta question here. These need to be addressed.

> The currently accepted answer

I see no accepted answer on that question. I checked the timeline and did not see any answer accepted at any time. (I don't read timelines very often so if I did miss something I'd appreciate the correction.)

> is actually an answer to a subtly different question, which also has unpleasant side effects (such as needless HTTP requests and errors in the console)

If by "currently accepted answer" you mean the one with the [most votes currently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14164706/1906307), the errors in the console are perhaps annoying to some but are not generally a deal breaker. I've got large applications running with RequireJS that do generate loading errors because my code tries to load some optional modules from a few places. They are harmless. It is *possible* that the code in that answer will result in an HTTP request but whether it will and whether it is "needless" really depends on the context in which it is run. There are situations where it is not possible to know a priori whether jQuery is available and in those situations performing an HTTP request at runtime to try to load it may be exactly what is needed to figure out whether the application can rely on jQuery.

> I worked hard to provide what I think is a good answer

It is a problematic answer.

The first part of your answer works but has a significant... hmm... quirk... The call `require.defined('jquery')` will return `true` only if jQuery has *already* been loaded. Normally, when you write a module that depends on jQuery, you put `jquery` in the dependency list of your module. Like this:

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) { ...
```

(For those not familiar with RequireJS: yes, it is `jquery` all lower caps. It is a source of endless confusion.)

Then, you don't have to worry about whether jQuery is *already* loaded: RequireJS will load it for you when it loads your module because your module makes it a dependency. (And I should point out that each encounter of `jquery` in a dependency list will **not** cause RequireJS to fetch it anew. At most, the first encounter will cause RequireJS to fetch it, and then RequireJS will remember whether it can resolve `jquery` or not.) Someone using your solution will now have to worry about writing code *elsewhere* that will set things correctly so that when the module that wants jQuery loads, the jQuery module has been loaded already. **This is brittle.** Moreover, a consequence of using `require.defined` is that if it returns `false`, there can be two possibilities:

1. jQuery *really* is unavailable. ("Unavailable" here means the application cannot load it, period, not "unavailable now but perhaps available in the future".)
2. Your application followed a code path that made it so that jQuery has just not been loaded *yet*, even though it *is* available (i.e. it can be loaded).

The UMD part suffers from the same problem and is addressing an issue that the OP did not need addressed.

I cannot read the mind of the downvoters but it seems to me there is material for downvotes here.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. Sorry, accepted was indeed supposed to be top-rated. Though I find it weird to address the technical issues here let me try.... Point is that OP is making a library that *may* use jQuery, but does not need it. Key word here is *library*, not *application*. Thus OP is most probably not in control of configuration.

Comment: OP does not want to force jQuery on lib users, but if they have it, wants to support/use it. He wants to do so using AMD. My solution offers just that. The lib can use Query if it's there, but does not load it by itself. Lib user must configure correctly, but that's always the case.

Comment: `It is a problematic answer. The first part of your answer works but has a significant... hmm... quirk...`  I beg to differ. Unless by `quirk` you mean that it's quirky if `$` is not available when `require.defined('jquery')` returns false? Compare with script tags. If you load *first* a jQuery plugin and *only then* jQuery itself, the plugin does not work. You consider that quirky? Same with the parallel loadin scenario. These scenarios translate directly to script tags with or without async and the order those tags are in. It's how HTML has always worked.

Comment: `Someone using your solution will now have to worry about writing code elsewhere that will set things correctly so that when the module that wants jQuery loads, the jQuery module has been loaded already. This is brittle.` It is not brittle. It is exactly what OP asked for. An *optional* dependency. OP's lib will *continue working no matter what*. This is the opposite of brittle. In fact, actively pulling in jQuery into a page on which the user of the lib had not loaded it seems obtrusive to me. It would not be the behavior I would expect of a lib that states to have no dependency on jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to see what happened with votes?

Yes.

There are many ways to see the reputation change/history.

1. As already told in other answer, click on the number between the voting arrows to **View upvote and downvote totals**.
2. Click on **Recent achievements** on the top to see the **reputation, badges and privileges earned**.
3. Go to

```
Activity page --> reputation tab --> post/time/graph
```

"Time" view is my preferred way to actually see the reputation history. "Post" view would simply sum up the totals.

---

On a side note : Linking your answer on meta should not be done with an expectation to get upvotes. The meta-effect is not always going to help you.